# Python: Getting a syntax error. Possibly due to incorrect installation of the PIL library

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-imaging-library

```
width, height = img.size
total = 0
for row in range(width):
    for col in range(height):
        # This will save the RGBA values of the pixel
        red, green, blue, alpha = img.getpixel( (row, col) )
        new_red = red + new_red
        new_green = green + new_green
        new_blue = blue + new_blue
        total = 1 + total

average_red = new_red/total
average_green = new_green/total
average_blue = new_blue/total
img.putpixel((row, col,), (average_red, average_green, average_blue, 255)
img.show()
```

I'm getting a syntax error when using that. I am guessing that it could be due to the incorrect installation of the PIL module.

Anybody aware if this is the case?

If so, can someone guide me to an installation guide on how to install it in Mac OSX?

Comment: Can you show more code please? Typically when you get a syntax error it is the line above.

Comment: @idjaw

I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `)` at the end of

```
img.putpixel((row, col), (average_red, average_green, average_blue, 255)
```

It should be

```
img.putpixel((row, col), (average_red, average_green, average_blue, 255))
```

Comment: Sweet! Some of the most stupid things can get the best of us!